# Google is still indexing my old pages

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

A few questions.

Why is google still looking at my old indexed pages and not my new index. ?

Why are they crawling my old website links when all of them are not available?

How do I overcome these problems?

Comment: Cleaning your browser cache?

Comment: How does that help ?

Comment: If you could provide a URL I could have a closer look at this. There could be a bunch of reasons for your problem.

Comment: Have you set up 301 correctly? How long have you waited? It generally takes weeks to completely transfer index to new domain.